# ldap_search to exclude emails

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

Consider the following.

```
$ad=ldap_connect("ldap.domain.local"); 
$dn_Accounting = 'OU=Accounting,OU=Users,OU=MyBusiness,DC=domain,DC=local';
$attributes = array("mail", "cn");
$filter = "(mail=*)";
$ldap_username = 'DOMAIN\\internalweb_ldap';
$ldap_password = 'password';
$bd=ldap_bind($ad, $ldap_username, $ldap_password); 
$result_Accounting = ldap_search($ad, $dn_Accounting, $filter, $attributes);
$entries_Accounting = ldap_get_entries($ad, $result_Accounting);
    for ($i=0; $i<$entries_Accounting["count"]; $i++){
        echo $entries_Accounting[$i]["cn"][0]." (".$entries_Accounting[$i]["mail"][0]."),<br />";
    }
```

How can I filter to exclude specific emails in the `$filter`?
For example, if I wanted to exclude `justin@domain.com` and `john@domain.com`, how would I need to phrase the filter to not include those emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$filter = "(&(mail=*)(!(mail=justin@domain.com))(!(mail=john@domain.com)))";
```

Answer (score 0):

$filter = '(&(mail=*)(!(|(mail=justin@domain.com)(mail=john@domain.com))))'

(I'm not sure about the closing parentheses currently).

The filter shall have a value in mail **and** must **not** contain one of justin@domain.com **or** john@domain.com.

Logical groups are combined in parentheses followed with one of '&' (AND) '|' (OR) or '!' (NOT).

Comment: I receive the following errors when using the above.
`ldap_search(): Search: Bad search filter in /var/www/search/search.php`

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience! The attribute-names have been missing in my filter. I've edited the answer accordingly so that it should work out now!